# makefile command to check if the module is writing data into a memory section

Tags: unix, memory-management, makefile

I am trying to change my makefile to inform when program puts the data into certain memory section.
For example if there are 2 memory sections asw0 and asw1. when the program puts data in asw1 section it has to be informed during the build.
I can check these manually by analyzing .map file. But is there any I can implement it makefile?

currently I am able to access .map file and display some of the information like below..

```
grep Total $(BUILD_DIR)/main.map
```

Thanks.

Comment: You want a new make target that can give you the information you want or you want to enhance a current make target to give you that information when you create the map file (or some other point)? What command(s) do you need to run to get the information you want? Is that `grep` command enough?

Comment: I would like to enhance a current make target to give that information.

Comment: And sorry, its during the linking stage where data of module is put in memory section. (in question I have wrongly mentioned as program ). I have the start and end address of the memory section asw1 so during linking if data is put in this section

Comment: What command(s) do you need to run to get that information from `main.map` or do you have that information in a variable already in make (because you have something that chooses that in make already)?

Comment: Is the question here how to do this in make or how to do this at all?

Comment: @EtanReisner I need to check the main.map file for section like below  `.data       6000747c  6000747f  00000004  src/test.o`
`.data       60007480  60007487  00000008  src/main.o`
  i.e whenever there is `.data` section for memory address ranging from _60005000 - 70000000_ then it means that data is in asw1 memory section. Then need to print an warning during building so that user is aware of that.

Comment: @EtanReisner - The question is to how to do this in make.

Comment: So forget about make for a minute. How would you do that at the shell? What *exact* commands would you run?

Comment: @EtanReisner In shell first I would a file grep for the pattern and write it to a new file  `grep '^.data' build/main.map > newfile.txt`  . And then parse the newfile.txt for the pattern with address range. If there are any hits then print message.This could not be the best method, since I am working with .map file first time, so this is the best I could think of. Please suggest if you know a easier way.

Comment: I've got no idea about *how* to do it in the first place. But if you know the commands you need to use then just write those in the makefile in the target you want them to be run during. (You shouldn't need a temporary file if you can just parse the output directly since you can pipe `grep` to `awk` or whatever to do that.)

Comment: Thanks for the input @EtanReisner. can you please give some hints how to parse output directly without the temp file? I need to parse the output for a pattern and then perform an action. I appreciate your help. :)

Comment: How were you planning to parse the file in the first place? Write that command (or series of commands). Assuming you are using `grep` or `awk` or `perl` or something like that they can all operate on standard input from a pipe as easily as they can operate on a temporary file. With `awk` or `perl` you could almost certainly avoid that first `grep` entirely in fact.

Comment: I came up with below cod `awk '/^.data/ {if ($3>=0x60000000&& $3<=70040000) print"MESSAGE DATA IN ASW1"}' build/main.map` . This works just fine in shell. But when I copied to makefile with `awk '/^.data/ {if ($3>=0x60000000&& $3<=70040000) print"MESSAGE DATA IN ASW1"}' $(BUILD_DIR)/main.map` it is giving error as _awk: cmd. line:1: /^.data/ {if (>=0x80000000&& <=80040000) print"MESSAGE DATA IN ASW1"}  build/main.map
awk: cmd. line:1:               ^ parse error
_ Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You need to double any `$` in the command to escape them from make.

Comment: Yes. realized it a bit later. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @EtanReisner we could add the shell commands directly to makefile. So in order to check in which section of the memory data is allocated we need to parse map file data section and then check the address range. I came up with this simple line of command which does the task perfectly.

`awk '/^.data/ {if ($3>=0x70000000&& $3<=70040000) print"\n!!WARNING:Initialized data section allocated in ASW0!!\n"}' $(BUILD_DIR)/main.map`

This parses the whole map file for data section and then checks address is within  ASW0 section. In that case it prints a warning message.